# Why window.onpageshow not running in android default browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, android-browser, pageshow

Currently i'm trying to check if user press back button when running my webpage.
I'm using `window.onpageshow` to check the experience. It works well in chrome and also safari.

My problem is window.onpageshow not working in Android default browser. Is it because the app is still not supporting `pageshow` attribute? Or is there any method other than using pageshow ?

`header('Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate,no-store');`  is already implemented in index.php

[image]